# How do i move the window buttons (close, minimize,maximize) in App Center

Tags: gnome, window-buttons, app-center

Recently updated to ubuntu 23.10. I have set the
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,maximize,minimize,:'
this affects all other programs, however for the App Center, the buttons stays to the right. Changing back and forth as well as restarting / using wayland and x the issue still persists. Any ideas?

Comment: Firmware Updater also doesn't follow it, while every other snap does. I opened [this issue](https://github.com/ubuntu/app-center/issues/1469). I hope it will get fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the developers answering the [issue report](https://github.com/ubuntu/app-center/issues/1469). This is a general limitation of the way Flutter applications are currently being developed for the Ubuntu desktop